# Adding to comboBox of previous form

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a comboBox in Form1 with login button and comboBox1 is disabled. When a user clicks on login button a new form Form3 opens for users to input username and password. If username and password is correct then comboBox1 is enabled and items are added to comboBox. I am implementing these things in following way. In Form1 when user click on login button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tep = new Form3();
    tep.ShowDialog();
}
```

In Form3 I have

```
 public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Enter UserName and Password .");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            const string f = @"users.txt";
            const string p = @"passwd.txt";
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(f);
            string[] lines1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(p);
            if (Array.IndexOf(lines, textBox1.Text) != -1 && Array.IndexOf(lines1, textBox2.Text) != -1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("correct");
                var df = new Form1();
                df.comboBox1.Enabled = true;
                df.comboBox1.Items.Add("line1");
                df.comboBox1.Items.Add("line2");
                this.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not Correct");
            }
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Thus if login is successful then comboBox1 is enabled and items are added to it as shown in above code but problem is that comboBox1 remains disabled and no items are added to it. Where am I making mistake?

Comment: The problem is that you are creating another instance of Form1, df is not pointing to the previous form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because you are creating new `Form1` and original one is still disabled.

Best way of doing that would be to use `DialogResult` like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tep = new Form3();
    if (tep.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        comboBox1.Enabled = true;
        comboBox1.Items.Add("line1");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("line2");
    }
}
```

and in `Form3`

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
  {
      MessageBox.Show(" Enter UserName and Password .");
      return;
  }
  else
  {
      const string f = @"users.txt";
      const string p = @"passwd.txt";
      string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(f);
      string[] lines1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(p);
      if (Array.IndexOf(lines, textBox1.Text) != -1 && Array.IndexOf(lines1, textBox2.Text) != -1)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("correct");
          this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
          this.Close();
      }
      else
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Not Correct");
      }
  }
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
  this.Close();
}
```

Comment: @user2673943 don't forget remove combo populating in the form3

Answer (score 0):

No need to create new object of Form1 in Form3.

Pass `Form1` object to the `Form3()` constructor as Form3(this) and instead of creating new `Form1()` object in  `public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` use the Form1 object that is passed through the constructor

in Form3

use

```
        Public Form1 form1;
        public Form3( Form1 form1Object)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            form1=form1Object;
        }
```

and use that object in public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) as

```
  form1.comboBox1.Enabled = true;
  form1.comboBox1.Items.Add("line1");
  form1.comboBox1.Items.Add("line2");
  this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
  this.Close();
```

And in Form1

modify as

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tep = new Form3(this);
    tep.ShowDialog();
    this.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: I advise not to use this as `Form3` should not know anything about `Form1` and manipulate internal controls of it (this is breaking encapsulation)

Comment: Passing `this` to the `Form3` is not safe, it is breaking encapsulation and the Law of Demeter